# Using batch script to import a registry tree (winXP)

Tags: import, batch-file, windows-xp, registry

I've backed up the registry tree containing the disk cleanup parameters (`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches]`), and I want to be able to restore that registry tree via a batch script.

Can it be done in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reg import
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742021(WS.10).aspx